# pyftdi with FT4232HL: missing last bit in every byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, spi, ftdi

The last bit of every byte is missing when reading data from SC18IS600.

Using pyftdi version 0.50.0 with FT4232HL FTDI chip reading registers from SC18IS600 ([SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface)-to-[I²C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) chip), I'm missing the last bit when reading its internal registers and from reading data from slave I²C chips.

I am using SPI mode 3 and a 100 kHz clock.

My code:

```
from pyftdi.spi import SpiController

spi = SpiController(cs_count=5,)

# Configure the first interface (IF/2) of the FTDI device as a SPI master
spi.configure('ftdi://ftdi:ft4232h:/2')

# Get a port to a SPI slave w/ /CS on B*BUS and SPI mode 3 @ 100 kHz
slave = spi.get_port(cs=2, freq=100e3, mode=3)

rtrn = slave.exchange([0x21, 0x00, 0x00], 1)
print(rtrn.hex())
```

The `rtrn` value is 0x0E, but the written value is 0x0F (register control GPIO I verify is HIGH after write).

It was tested with an oscilloscope on the FTDI SPI lines, and I can verify the 0x0F:

[image: Oscilloscope with SPI decode]

Green: CS, Yellow: clock, Purple: MOSI, Orange: MISO

I contacted [NXP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NXP_Semiconductors) support and from the image below, they say everything is good with the command and structure sent to the chip and the return values are good.

[SC18IS600 datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/SC18IS600.pdf)

How can I solve this?

Comment: What happens when you try SPI modes 0, 1, or 2?

Comment: SPI 0,1,2 all return values are 0.

Comment: What happens if you increase the `1` argument for `slave.exchange` to e.g. `2`?

Comment: You will get the same register again, 0x0e0e

Answer (score 0):

Check that the mode is *really* set to 3. You can confirm by checking the values of:
slave._cpha and slave._cpol

I've found that get_port() doesn't actually set the mode and you need to explicitly change the mode with:
slave.set_mode(mode = 3)

Comment: the mode was really 3 slave._cpha and slave._cpol are set to "True", the developer of pyftdi said that mode 3 is not supported officially, Thanks for trying!